# After running nmp run serve from Command Promt Prompt does not become available

Tags: node.js

After running npm run serve  I receive a message saying

```
Server listening at localhost:8888
```

But

now I don't get the prompt back it just got stuck there
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

That is normal, no command prompt as the server is still running until you hit CTRL-C to stop it.  However, it is possible to do what you want by adding an ampersand "&" at the end of your command.  Example:

```
npm run &
```

It should show you the PID number after it runs, so to kill it type:

```
kill <whatever the PID number is>
```

Didn't see the PID number??  type this to list running processes:

```
ps -aef
```

Alternate way is to use "screen" or "tmux", which allows you to multiplex the terminal.

Comment: Thanks but    I did Contrl+C to close it for a fresh start and then wrote " nmp run serve &" and got to see the PID number just before the message where the Server listening at localhost:8888 comes up, the thing is I can't kill anything because I can;t write anything, the prompt is just not there

Comment: as long as you didn't get any errors when you ran it, you just wait a few seconds and the command prompt should return.  If not, you can use Screen:
https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

or tmux:
https://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/

Comment: Thank you Mark, TMux looks very good, too bad I can't use it her because I am running under windows.

Comment: Man, so sorry.  I'm out of ideas other than opening a second terminal window.  Best of luck, hope someone has better ideas!!